# Getting your Data Horizontially From A Veriticle Database For Charting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to create a chart by querying a table in our database.

I am having trouble understanding how to get the data horizontally from the database so it plugs into the chart nicely.

How do people normally get data prepared for a chart which excepts the data to be inputted horizontally?

I'm using PHP and mysql.

My->Mysql Query =:

> ```
> SELECT SUM( production_net ) AS prodnet, production_shift, CONCAT( WEEK( production_date ) , '-', YEAR( production_date )) AS weekno
>     FROM production
>     WHERE production_shift IN('1','2','3')
>     AND product_id = '1319'
>     AND production_date
>     BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
>     AND '2013-06-30'
>     GROUP BY production_shift, weekno
>     ORDER BY production_shift, CASE weekno
>     WHEN '0-2013' THEN 1
>     WHEN '1-2013' THEN 2
>     WHEN '2-2013' THEN 3
>     WHEN '3-2013' THEN 4
>     WHEN '4-2013' THEN 5
>     WHEN '5-2013' THEN 6
>     WHEN '6-2013' THEN 7
>     WHEN '7-2013' THEN 8
>     WHEN '8-2013' THEN 9
>     WHEN '9-2013' THEN 10
>     WHEN '10-2013' THEN 11
>     WHEN '11-2013' THEN 12
>     WHEN '12-2013' THEN 13
>     WHEN '13-2013' THEN 14
>     WHEN '14-2013' THEN 15
>     WHEN '15-2013' THEN 16
>     WHEN '16-2013' THEN 17
>     WHEN '17-2013' THEN 18
>     WHEN '18-2013' THEN 19
>     WHEN '19-2013' THEN 20
>     WHEN '20-2013' THEN 21
>     WHEN '21-2013' THEN 22
>     WHEN '22-2013' THEN 23
>     WHEN '23-2013' THEN 24
>     WHEN '24-2013' THEN 25
>     WHEN '25-2013' THEN 26
>     WHEN '26-2013' THEN 27
>     WHEN '27-2013' THEN 28
>     WHEN '28-2013' THEN 29
>     WHEN '29-2013' THEN 30
>     WHEN '30-2013' THEN 31
>     WHEN '31-2013' THEN 32
>     WHEN '32-2013' THEN 33
>     WHEN '33-2013' THEN 34
>     WHEN '34-2013' THEN 35
>     WHEN '35-2013' THEN 36
>     WHEN '36-2013' THEN 37
>     WHEN '37-2013' THEN 38
>     WHEN '38-2013' THEN 39
>     WHEN '39-2013' THEN 40
>     WHEN '40-2013' THEN 41
>     WHEN '41-2013' THEN 42
>     WHEN '42-2013' THEN 43
>     WHEN '43-2013' THEN 44
>     WHEN '44-2013' THEN 45
>     WHEN '45-2013' THEN 46
>     WHEN '46-2013' THEN 47
>     WHEN '47-2013' THEN 48
>     WHEN '48-2013' THEN 49
>     WHEN '49-2013' THEN 50
>     WHEN '50-2013' THEN 51
>     WHEN '51-2013' THEN 52
>     WHEN '52-2013' THEN 53
>     WHEN '53-2013' THEN 54
>     WHEN '54-2013' THEN 55
>     END
> ```

```
producation_date    shift   part_net
2013-01-12          1   810
2013-01-13          1   1537
2013-01-14          1   731
2013-01-15          1   75
2013-01-16          1   326
2013-01-17          1   786
2013-01-18          1   1586
2013-01-19          1   1739
2013-01-20          1   1740
2013-01-21          1   1215
2013-01-22          1   1004
2013-01-12          2   978
2013-01-13          2   721
2013-01-14          2   736
2013-01-15          2   593
2013-01-16          2   1560
2013-01-17          2   617
2013-01-18          2   1540
2013-01-19          2   458
2013-01-20          2   259
2013-01-21          2   1419
2013-01-22          2   66
2013-01-12          3   551
2013-01-13          3   1643
2013-01-14          3   1244
2013-01-15          3   376
2013-01-16          3   1540
2013-01-17          3   1381
2013-01-18          3   472
2013-01-19          3   194
2013-01-20          3   2043
2013-01-21          3   1345
2013-01-22          3   97
```

What I need is this data like this

```
producation_date    shift_1_net shift_2_net shift_3_net
2013-01-12          810         2078            1060
2013-01-13          344         1839            922
2013-01-14          1720            1771            1665
2013-01-15          969         61          733
2013-01-16          117         596         1356
2013-01-17          1716            826         55
2013-01-18          1442            463         1597
2013-01-19          763         1895            571
2013-01-20          1633            148         1916
2013-01-21          67          1503            573
2013-01-22          85          763         800
```

I've been trying array_merge/push/ and chunk but can't get the data correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(WEEK(production_date), '-', YEAR(production_date)) weekno,
    SUM(CASE WHEN production_shift = 1 THEN production_net ELSE 0 END) shift_1_net,
    SUM(CASE WHEN production_shift = 2 THEN production_net ELSE 0 END) shift_2_net,
    SUM(CASE WHEN production_shift = 3 THEN production_net ELSE 0 END) shift_3_net,
WHERE production_shift IN(1, 2, 3) AND product_id = 1319 AND
    production_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30'
GROUP BY weekno
ORDER BY YEAR(production_date), WEEK(production_date)
```

BTW, I think the `ORDER BY` returns rows in the same order as yours and is a bit simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

Mostacho had it nearly perfect, I had to remove a comma, add the table I was pulling from and still use the huge case statement at the end. All credit to him, but here is my working query. Hope it helps others

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(WEEK(production_date), '-', YEAR(production_date)) weekno,
    SUM(CASE WHEN production_shift = '1' THEN production_net ELSE 0 END) shift_1_net,
    SUM(CASE WHEN production_shift = '2' THEN production_net ELSE 0 END) shift_2_net,
    SUM(CASE WHEN production_shift = '3' THEN production_net ELSE 0 END) shift_3_net
    FROM production
WHERE production_shift IN('1', '2', '3') AND product_id = '1319' AND
    production_date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-06-30'
    GROUP BY weekno
ORDER BY production_shift, CASE weekno
WHEN '0-2013' THEN 1
WHEN '1-2013' THEN 2
WHEN '2-2013' THEN 3
WHEN '3-2013' THEN 4
WHEN '4-2013' THEN 5
WHEN '5-2013' THEN 6
WHEN '6-2013' THEN 7
WHEN '7-2013' THEN 8
WHEN '8-2013' THEN 9
WHEN '9-2013' THEN 10
WHEN '10-2013' THEN 11
WHEN '11-2013' THEN 12
WHEN '12-2013' THEN 13
WHEN '13-2013' THEN 14
WHEN '14-2013' THEN 15
WHEN '15-2013' THEN 16
WHEN '16-2013' THEN 17
WHEN '17-2013' THEN 18
WHEN '18-2013' THEN 19
WHEN '19-2013' THEN 20
WHEN '20-2013' THEN 21
WHEN '21-2013' THEN 22
WHEN '22-2013' THEN 23
WHEN '23-2013' THEN 24
WHEN '24-2013' THEN 25
WHEN '25-2013' THEN 26
WHEN '26-2013' THEN 27
WHEN '27-2013' THEN 28
WHEN '28-2013' THEN 29
WHEN '29-2013' THEN 30
WHEN '30-2013' THEN 31
WHEN '31-2013' THEN 32
WHEN '32-2013' THEN 33
WHEN '33-2013' THEN 34
WHEN '34-2013' THEN 35
WHEN '35-2013' THEN 36
WHEN '36-2013' THEN 37
WHEN '37-2013' THEN 38
WHEN '38-2013' THEN 39
WHEN '39-2013' THEN 40
WHEN '40-2013' THEN 41
WHEN '41-2013' THEN 42
WHEN '42-2013' THEN 43
WHEN '43-2013' THEN 44
WHEN '44-2013' THEN 45
WHEN '45-2013' THEN 46
WHEN '46-2013' THEN 47
WHEN '47-2013' THEN 48
WHEN '48-2013' THEN 49
WHEN '49-2013' THEN 50
WHEN '50-2013' THEN 51
WHEN '51-2013' THEN 52
WHEN '52-2013' THEN 53
WHEN '53-2013' THEN 54
WHEN '54-2013' THEN 55
END
```